# Do multiple land claim blocks still prevent zombie spawning?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

The [Land Claim Block](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Land_Claims) (LCB) is now used in both multiplayer and singleplayer. Most notably, user-crafted workstations (workbenches, cement mixers, forges, etc) need to be within the realm of a placed LCB in order to be removed. Hitting it with a wrench or other tool will just destroy it.

The question: If I put multiple LCBs down (multiple bases, etc), I know that only the most recent LCB placed affects the workstations (I've already experienced this and had to put down a new LCB in order to move my forges to another location) but if I leave LCBs in place in an old base, placing a new one elsewhere, will the original LCB prevent zombie spawns in that area?

**TL;DR:**
I'm building an underground tunnel system between parts of my base, which spans more than the 41x41 space that a single LCB affects, so if I put multiple LCBs down in various areas, can I effectively prevent all zombie spawning inside my bases?

Comment: In regards to LCB they are suppose to be active simultaneously, however, there is a bug a few of us experience in SP where a LCB randomly stops working and we have to pick it up and re-place it. Also in general, while player blocks in custom bases do prevent spawns, screamers can still spawn zeds inside your base if it is huge and if you walk away and the chunk unloads I have occasionally found Zombies in my base when going back, loading the chunk back in. TFP has to fix that so we can build mega defensive bases IMHO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research shows that LCB doesn't stop spawning.  There isn't anything super conclusive, but it looks like the following stops spawning:

- Your bedroll (41x41 area by default)
- Player made "building blocks" (specific types of things classify)

There isn't any mention of LCB stopping spawning.

On top of that, certain types of spawning are not affected, like Sleeper in POI.  If you build an existing POI into your base, some respawns may not be preventable.

Sources:

[March 2016 reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/7daystodie/comments/5wys9x/how_can_i_prevent_zombies_from_spawning/)

[A16 release notes](http://7daystodie.com/a16-early-streaming-release-notes/)

Comment: This is correct, TS - accept this answer. I took over POI and even after full upgrade or destruction of original blocks, I got sleepers every time when there were no one at home (i.e when we all left for raid).

Comment: That's while using a LCB at your POI base?

Comment: [This Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/1354868867720493635/) contradicts what you said. I've seen arguments on both sides, although I admit that the LCB wiki page says nothing about blocking spawns, but it doesn't say that it doesn't block spawns.

Comment: But that post is just some guy saying LCB stops spawns in a radius, but there isn't any actual information based on that, and nobody reported whether it works or not.

What usually happens is if you got enough resources to start dropping LCB, you got resources to reinforce, and that's actually what typically stops spawns.  When you start digging up all the dirt and putting in cobblestones.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no prohibition on spawning on player-placed blocks. There is a property on blocks, player-placed or not, that allows non-POI, non-screamer spawns called canMobsSpawnOn. I don't know specifically which blocks have this property set or not but you can look in the items.xml file to check (I think). Further, if you remove this property (or set it to false) for those blocks where it is true, mobs will no longer spawn on that block type. Note that, as I understand it, screamers are not bound by this rule (nor are the mobs they call), and POI sleeper spawning, as it works with a different mechanism, is also not bound by this rule.

So if you added < property name='canMobsSpawnOn' value='false' /> to the entry for flagstoneBlock, then zombies would not spawn on those blocks. I've also read that zombies only spawn on the 'highest' block for a specific coordinate (outside a POI, of course). So, placing your base underground would keep you safe from general mobs spawns. I expect that will change pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

LCB does prevent zombie respawn. Multiple LCBs do not change this. It is now possible, in A18, to build a larger defensible position, including building with an existing POI because the LCB will prevent all respawns (including loot) within the boundary of that block.